# Is there a way to use fullcalendar with a public Google Calendar that only shows busy/free time?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

Is there a way to use the fullcalendar plugin with a public Google Calendar that only shows busy/free time?

The idea is not only to display only free/busy time, but really to work with a calendar that only shows busy and free time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fullcalendar uses the XML feel of a Google Calendar to create the events.  Seeing as the "public but showing only busy/free time" option in Google Calendar does not create an XML feed with sufficient information, fullcalendar can't read it properly.  So the answer is: no.

However, there are other ways to do this.  Here's what I did (and it works a charm).
With Google Cal, you can share your public XML feed, but you can also get your own private XML feed.  Using PHP, I worked with the very intuitive and easy [Coreylib](https://github.com/collegeman/coreylib) library to parse the XML.  Then I putthe wanted info (startTime and endTime) and in an array.  This array was then used when initializing fullcalendar to create custom events.

I'm posting the PHP bit because I really struggled to get the syntax right to fetch data from the clApi object.

```
// Feed can be grabbed from Google Cal settings -> get private feed, and change the "basic" to "full" at the end of the URL
$XMLfeed = "https://feed";

// Coreylib is used to parse the google cal XML
require_once('coreylib.php');

$api = new clApi($XMLfeed);
$feed = $api->parse();

foreach( $feed->get('entry') as $entry) {
  $start = $entry->get('when@startTime');
  $end = $entry->get('when@endTime');
  $allEvents[] = array('startTime'->$start, 'endTime'->$end);
}
```

And then I looped through $allEvents to create events in the JS init.

Hoping this can help someone.

Comment: Been struggling with this for ages. Didn't see the 'basic' on the end!